# Getting error in inserting data to sql database

Tags: php, sql

This is my code :

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');

    DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'root');
    DEFINE ('DB_PSWD', '');
    DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'facebooklogin');
    $connection = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PSWD) or die(mysql_error());
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

    $register_firstname = $_POST['register_password'];
    $register_lastname = $_POST['register_password'];
    $register_username = $_POST['register_username'];
    $register_password = $_POST['register_password'];
    $register_confirm_password = $_POST['register_confirm_password'];
    $register_email = $_POST['register_email'];

    $register_firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($register_firstname);
    $register_lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($register_lastname);
    $register_username = mysql_real_escape_string($register_username);
    $register_password = mysql_real_escape_string($register_password);
    $register_confirm_password = mysql_real_escape_string($register_confirm_password);
    $register_email = mysql_real_escape_string($register_email);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$register_username'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($count == 1){
        echo "That username is taken. Please try another.";
    }else{
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$register_email'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($count == 1){
            echo "That email is already in use. Please try again.";
        }else{
            if(strlen($register_firstname) == 0 or strlen($register_lastname) == 0 or strlen($register_username) == 0 or strlen($register_password) == 0 or strlen($register_confirm_password) == 0 or strlen($register_email) == 0){
                echo "Please complete all forms.";
            }else if(strlen($register_username) < 3 or strlen($register_username) > 12){
                echo "Username must be between 3 and 12 characters.";
            }else if(strlen($register_password) < 5 or strlen($register_password) > 12){
                echo "Password must be between 5 and 12 characters.";
            }else if($register_password != $register_confirm_password){
                echo "Passwords do not match. Please try again.";
            }else{
                $dbinsert = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, first_name, last_name, email) VALUES ('$register_username', '$register_password', '$register_firstname', '$register_lastname', '$register_email')";
                if(!mysqli_query($dbinsert)){
                    die("Error registering new user in database.");
                }
                echo "Registered!";
            } 
        }
    }
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>registered</title>
</head>
</html>
```

When I run this I get 2 error: Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead

and

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given

Can someone figure what is the error in this code and please fix it.

Comment: You are mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` at one time in same code. you should use only `mysqli_*` as `mysql_* is depreciated.

Comment: what about this? mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters @TimBezhashvyly

Comment: `else if` -> `elseif`

Answer (score 1):

Since, you are using `mysql_*` everywhere in your code. It seems the problem is in your `else` statement. You should use `mysql_query` not `mysqli_query` in your else statement.

```
else{
 $dbinsert = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, first_name, last_name, email) VALUES ('$register_username', '$register_password', '$register_firstname', '$register_lastname', '$register_email')";
 if(!mysql_query($connection,$dbinsert)){
 die("Error registering new user in database.");
  }
```

**P.S: you should consider using [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of `mysql` as it is depreciated and will be removed later.**

Comment: This is wrong suggestion `You should use mysql_* not mysqli_*` mysqli is more safer than mysql connection. Maybe not `should`, but `could`

Comment: Pardon Sir, since, OP is having problem in his code related to `mysqli_query` So, I have just pointed him out. @StanislovasKalašnikovas

Comment: Never recommend to a user that they use deprecated functions!  That is the source of the first error the user received.  <headdesk />.  Also don't "consider."  Definitely do this.  This is why these errors are popping out.  These functions will be gone from php very soon and will no longer work.

Comment: I will keep in mind your suggestion. Thanks for pointing me out. @nomistic.. Since, I just answered as per OP's stated problem to help him out.

Comment: what should I do? I 'am still getting error  sql is deprecated

Comment: @nomistic i'm still getting error

Comment: What PHP version you are using in your application? @KumariAnjali

Comment: Note, , software security is fairly serious.   Yes, you can get the code working using old code on local servers, but as soon as you start to put it live, you may run into trouble or worse, you end up with major code vulnerabilities.  I generally find it better not to develop bad habits, as the user will end up having to rewrite all of their code (I speak from personal experience.  I shudder at some of my older code) :)

Comment: I am totally agreeing with you @nomistic and you have put most valuable information for me as a part of suggestion. :)

Comment: @KumariAnjali, I've added a few more edits below to help you out.  I know it may seem like a lot to consider, but once you go this direction you'll find it's not any more difficult, and the coding process will be cleaner and faster amongst all the other benefits :)

Answer (score 0):

Your errors are coming from two places.

1. The first one refers to a the fact that `mysql_connect` is **deprecated**.  This is a serious warning your code is giving you.  Yes, you could correct your code to make it work, but it ***will stop working*** in future versions of php.
2. The syntax for `mysqli_query` requires a connection to the database as a parameter.  To use this properly use

`mysqli_query($conection,$dbinsert)`

like so:

```
if(!mysqli_query($conection,$dbinsert)){
                die("Error registering new user in database.");
            }
```

Note you will need to do the same thing up here (and any other place you are using the deprecated functions:

```
 $result = mysql_query($query);
```

should be:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

etc. also look at your mysql_num_rows and use something like this:   http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_num_rows.asp

**One more edit:**
look at any php connection in your code connecting to your database that uses the old `mysql_` syntax and update it. This includes `mysql_connect`, `mysql_select_db`, `mysql_real_escape_string`, `mysql_query`, `mysql_num_rows`, and any other place where you tend to use these.

There are other options other than `mysqli` such as `PDO`.  Both are fine.  Also I seriously suggest looking into preparing your statements.   This will both speed up large inserts, updates, selects, etc, but also a) increase security (they virtually remove most sql injection attacks;  at least the script-kiddie ones), and b) remove any need to remember to escape all of your variables (a nice bonus).

Comment: of course if you want the errors (the notices) to go away (not advisable in the coding process), you can just remove the error reporting rows at the top of your code.  However, I do *not* recommend this